# Single instance .NET Core App (or making crontab run only 1 instance of my app)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, cron, .net-core

I would like to execute a .NET Core Application on a **schedule** in Linux using **crontab**. It's a long running operation and **I don't want another instance to be run if a previous execution hasn't finished yet**. In other words, I don't want **crontab** to execute more than one instance of my .NET Core App at a given time.

Is there any way to avoid it? I would prefer not to modify the code of my app. Maybe there is an option for crontab to avoid concurrency. I'm not a Linux expert (yet) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally used a little tool available for Raspbian: **flock**

In my crontab config file, I've put this:

```
flock -n /tmp/importer.lock dotnet ~/Desktop/Importer/Plugin.Clm.Importer.Console.dll
```

It seems that flock writes a lock file while it's running, and executes the command. It it's executed again, and the lock file is there, it just fails. When it finishes, it releases the file, allowing it to be called again.

In a few words: it acts as a semaphore :)

Answer (score 9):

For those who want to check instances from code you may use named mutex like this

```
const string mutexName = @"Global\appName";

var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out var createdNew);

if (!createdNew)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mutexName + " is already running! Exiting the application.");
    return;
}
```

Be sure that your mutex name begins with `"Global\"`.

Comment: `Mutex` has thread affinity, which means you can't use it with `async` code, so `Semaphore` is a better choice if you can use it (named `Semaphores` are not supported under Linux at the moment, for example).

Comment: @13xforever do you realy need async code when performing check at the start of the programm?

Comment: @xneg it is helpful for when you use the new `async Task Main() {}` signature

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it in your program, you could loop through all processes in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses and check if any process executable path ends with your filename.

```
[System.STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.MainModule.FileName.EndsWith("bla.exe", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Otherwise, have a script set a value in /var/run and check if that file exists. That file is to be deleted if your program exits in any way.

Also, address the long running time.
Programs should't normally take that long.
Looks to me like you're doing something wrong, unless you are indeed processing several gigabytes of data.

if MainModule returns dotnet, you could also readlink proc/pid/exe/ (Linux or BSD) or /proc/self/exe (linux only)

```
   int pid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(System.Environment.SystemPageSize);
   int ret = Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.readlink($"/proc/{pid}/exe", sb);
   string res = sb.ToString();
   System.Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Alternatively, if that only yields dotnet too, you can read the command line arguments (/proc/pid/cmdline - linux only):

```
public static byte[] ReadReallyAllBytes(string filename)
{
    byte[] retValue = null;

    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[System.Environment.SystemPageSize];
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
        int ct = 0;
        while ((ct = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ct; ++i)
            {
                byteList.Add(buffer[i]);
            }
        }

        buffer = null;
        retValue = byteList.ToArray();
        byteList.Clear();
        byteList = null;
    }

    return retValue;
}


public static List<string> GetCmdLineArgs(int pid)            
{
    List<string> ls = new List<string>();                

    byte[] buffer = ReadReallyAllBytes($"/proc/{pid}/cmdline");
    int last = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == 0)
        {
            string arg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, last, i-last);
            last = i + 1;
            ls.Add(arg);
        } // End if (buffer[i] == 0)

    } // Next i 

    // System.Console.WriteLine(ls);
    return ls;
}
```

Now if MainModule is dotnet, check if the command line arguments list contains your dll/exe. 
Also, if you do a release-build (standalone - no shared-framework), then it should work with MainModule.

Comment: Sometimes long-running processes are due to multiple checks throughout the day with pauses between checks (IE every hour do this check if result process the data)

Comment: @hellyale: Since cron calls your process i.e. every hour, there's no need for the program to keep running after it finished... Otherwise you wouldn't need cron.

Comment: Your first solution will not work since `Process.MainModule.FileName` would be always 'dotnet' for every NET Core app.

Comment: @xneg: Proper way: readlink /proc/<PID>/exe (Linux, BSD), or readlink /proc/self/exe (Linux only)

Comment: @StefanSteiger how do you apply this in code. Can you give an example?

Comment: @xneg: Added example. But forget readlink, that also just returns dotnet, you need to read /proc/<PID>/cmdline

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the duplicate check in the script, not in the program.

So check the output of 'ps -ef | grep myprogramname' before executing your program.